# Variance of the random variable representing the outcome of a dice roll

Tags: probability, random-variables

The six faces of an ordinary dice are numbered to 1 to 6 in the usual fashion, where the total in opposite faces adds up to 7.

Let $X$ be the random variable representing the outcome when the dice is rolled. Calculate the variance of $X$.

Can anyone explain how to calculate the variance?

Answer (score 0):

The variance is $\sum_{i=1}^n p(x_i)\cdot (x_i-\mu)^2$. You probably know that $\mu=3.5$.

And $p(x_i)$ is constant $\frac{1}{6} \quad \forall i \in \{ 1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Therefore $p(x_i)=\frac{1}{6}$ can be factored out:

$var(X)=\frac{1}{6}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n  (x_i-3.5)^2$. You have 6 possible outcomes ($x_i$): $1,2,3,4,5,6 $.

Now you just have to insert the values: $var(X)=\frac{1}{6}\cdot \left[(1-3.5)^2+(2-3.5)^2+(3-3.5)^2+\ldots \right]$